# MoveBaseAction cancel_goal does not work from python script

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote some simple python script which is trying to cancel current goal.

The problem is that nothing happens, goal is not cancelling.

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong and why nothing happens?

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import actionlib
##from move_base_msgs.msg import MoveBaseAction, MoveBaseGoal
from move_base_msgs.msg import MoveBaseAction, MoveBaseGoal
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from math import sqrt
##from std_msgs.msg import Empty

class mbSmoother():
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('mbSmoother', anonymous=True)

        self.move_base = actionlib.SimpleActionClient("/move_base", MoveBaseAction)
        rospy.loginfo("Waiting for move_base action server...")
        # Wait 60 seconds for the action server to become available
        self.move_base.wait_for_server(rospy.Duration(60))
        rospy.loginfo("Connected to move base server")
        rospy.loginfo("Starting move base goals smoother")

        rospy.Subscriber("/odom", Odometry, self.odomCallback)
        rospy.Subscriber("/move_base/current_goal", PoseStamped, self.goalCallback)

        rospy.spin()

    def odomCallback(self, msg):
        self.robot_pose = msg.pose.pose
        ##print "odom:"
        ##print self.robot_pose

    def goalCallback(self, msg):
        self.goal_pose = msg.pose
        ##print "goal:"
        ##print self.goal_pose
        while True:
            self.distance = sqrt(pow(self.goal_pose.position.x - self.robot_pose.position.x, 2) + pow(self.goal_pose.position.y - self.robot_pose.position.y, 2))
            print self.distance
            if self.distance < 0.5:
                self.move_base.cancel_goal()
                ##rospy.sleep(4)
                ##wait = self.move_base.wait_for_result()
                rospy.loginfo("goal has been canceled")
                break
                
        ##while self.goal_pose.position.x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mbSmoother()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340635/movebaseaction-cancel_goal-does-not-work-from-python-script/) by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-12-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know about the python client but as far as I remember, sending an empty message to this topic like this cancels all goals:

```
rostopic pub -1 /move_base/cancel actionlib_msgs/GoalID -- {}
```

This works in terminal well.

You can send the message in python like:

```
from actionlib_msgs.msg import GoalID
cancel_pub = rospy.Publisher("/move_base/cancel", GoalID, queue_size=1)
cancel_msg = GoalID()
cancel_pub.publish(cancel_msg)
```

Just tried these lines in python terminal to be sure and it works.

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2019-12-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`self.move_base.cancel_goal()` only works if your `self.move_base` object has sent the goal itself on the first place. Which I don't think is the case.

What @Orhan suggested in his answer can actually be accomplished by: `self.move_base.cancel_all_goals()`.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2019-12-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2019-12-26**:
Cleaner and the correct one.